# It's possible to limit the number of nested plugins in django-cms?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I've got a simple question. I want to know if it's possible to define a limit number of child plugins in `django-cms`. My plugin has child plugins but I wanna to limit the number of child plugins to a maximum of 2. It's possible to do it adding some configuration to the `cms_plugins.py` ? Without having to add a form and validate it by hand?

I added this to `settings.py`:

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'Ipp_Article_Sidebar': {
        'plugins': ['ArticlesParentCMSPlugin', 'ArticlesChildCMSPlugin'],
        'name': gettext("Right Side Content"),
        'limits': {
            'ArticlesParentCMSPlugin': 1,
            'ArticlesChildCMSPlugin': 2
        }
    },
}
```

My placeholder belong to a model:

```
sidebar = PlaceholderField('ipp_article_sidebar',
                           related_name='IPP_ARTICLE_SIDEBAR')
```

But I can still add more than 2 childs.

Comment: See http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf

Comment: @mishbah I updated my question can you take a look? :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this cannot be done in Django CMS for nested plugins.

I needed something similar and made a quick workaround by overriding the template. I added a reaction to a similar question on Github: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/5102#issuecomment-278303995

Simply add `max_children = <number>` to your `Plugin` class and create a new `dragitem.html` template in your templates folder `templates/cms/toolbar/` to override the existing Django CMS template. See the diff below:

This nicely disabled the + icon when the maximum number of children has been reached.

```
--- env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/templates/cms/toolbar/dragitem.html       2016-09-15 12:06:26.132803200 +0200
+++ templates/cms/toolbar/dragitem.html    2017-02-08 12:26:59.343312100 +0100
@@ -9,6 +9,17 @@
         {% if plugin.child_plugin_instances %} cms-dragitem-collapsable{% endif %}">
         {% language request.toolbar.toolbar_language %}
         {% if not disabled_child %}
+            {% with max_children=plugin.get_plugin_instance.1.max_children child_count=plugin.child_plugin_instances|length %}
+                {% if max_children %}
+                    <div class="cms-submenu-btn cms-submenu-add cms-btn
+                        {% if child_count >= max_children %} cms-btn-disabled{% endif %}">
+                        {% if child_count >= max_children %}
+                            <span class="cms-hover-tooltip" data-cms-tooltip="{% trans "You cannot add plugins to this plugin." %}"></span>
+                        {% else %}
+                            <span class="cms-hover-tooltip cms-hover-tooltip-left cms-hover-tooltip-delay" data-cms-tooltip="{% trans "Add plugin" %}"></span>
+                        {% endif %}
+                    </div>
+                {% else %}
             <div class="cms-submenu-btn cms-submenu-add cms-btn
                 {% if not allow_children %} cms-btn-disabled{% endif %}">
                 {% if not allow_children %}
@@ -17,6 +28,8 @@
                 <span class="cms-hover-tooltip cms-hover-tooltip-left cms-hover-tooltip-delay" data-cms-tooltip="{% trans "Add plugin" %}"></span>
                 {% endif %}
             </div>
+                {% endif %}
+            {% endwith %}
             <div class="cms-submenu-btn cms-submenu-edit cms-btn" data-rel="edit">
                 <span class="cms-hover-tooltip cms-hover-tooltip-left cms-hover-tooltip-delay" data-cms-tooltip="{% trans "Edit" %}"></span>
             </div>
```